# Can't use c++17 features using g++ 7.2 in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, c++17, variant

I have recently updated gcc and g++ to version 7.2. I would like to try out `std::experimental::any` and `std::variant` in particular, and I am using Qt 5.9.1 in QtCreator.

So far I have written this in the project file:

```
CONFIG += c++17
```

And I have added the correct headers in the correct places:

```
#include <variant>
#include <experimental/any>
```

Any works fine, no problems there. However, when I include the variant header file, I get this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/c++17_warning.h:32: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2017 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17 compiler options.
```

#error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^~~~~

I have tried a variety of things in the project file, here is the full list:

```
CONFIG += c++17
```

&

```
CONFIG += c++1z
```

&

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
```

&

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1z
```

&

```
CONFIG += c++17
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
```

&

```
CONFIG += c++1z
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1z
```

&

```
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += c++17
```

That's every stab in the dark I could think of. What am I missing? And why does `experimental::any` compile when variant doesn't?

I know I shouldn't use `CONFIG += c++xx` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` together in this way, but I thought I'd give it a go as nothing else works. For bonus points, I'm also wondering, should I add the CONFIG calls for 14 and 11 when I already CONFIG for 17?

EDIT:

Here is the compiler output with most of my filenames scrubbed out:

```
18:04:10: Running steps for project AIQt...
18:04:10: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:04:10: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/pete/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake -o Makefile ../AIQt/AIQt.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
WARNING: Failure to find: ../src/stdafx.h
WARNING: Failure to find: ../src/Csound/csd.h
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DATAVISUALIZATION_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../AIQt -I. -I../src -I../src/AIBase -I../src/Maths -I../src/Random -isystem /usr/local/include/csound -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtDataVisualization -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I../../../../Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../AIQt/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/variant:35:0,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/c++17_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2017 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^~~~~
In file included from ..###,
                 from ..###
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###:
../src/AIBase/Geno.h:70:18: error: ‘variant’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
             std::variant m_valueVariant;
                  ^~~~~~~
In file included from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###,
                 from ..###:
../src/AIBase/Pheno.h:22:13: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
             const double getGenoValue(size_t genoIndex) const;
             ^~~~~
../src/AIBase/Pheno.h:24:13: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
             const UserRating getRating() const;
             ^~~~~
In file included from ..###,
                 from ..###:
../AIRadioQt/GraphDialog.h:16:15: warning: declaration ‘struct ar::ai::ClusterList’ does not declare anything
 class ar::ai::ClusterList;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
18:04:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AIQt (kit: Qt 5.9.1 GCC 64bit)
The kit Qt 5.9.1 GCC 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
18:04:13: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

ANSWER:

As mentioned by nwp, I just had to clean it and rebuild.

Another poster also commented that `CONFIG += c++17` doesn't appear to be supported yet, so it is necessary to use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17`. He quickly deleted his comment though, so I am unable to thank him personally for going to the effort of checking the docs for me.

Comment: In the bottom there should be a tab "Compile Output". What flags starting with "-std=" are there? Note that there may be multiple of them and only the last one counts.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think to check. It mentions no -std= flags. Do I need to add the CONFIG line in a specific place? Compiler output is added to question...

Comment: Rightclick on your project and select "clean" and then "Run qmake". For reasons I will never understand changing the .pro file doesn't always update the makefile properly.

Comment: Hot damn! As long as I'm using QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17, and not the CONFIG equivalent, it works after I cleaned and rebuild. Thanks man! Someone did briefly write a comment about the docs not showing support for CONFIG += c++17. He deleted his comment, but if he's reading this, that was a helpful thing to say. Feel free to write that comment again and I'll upvote it, haha. But yes, rebuilding was the answer, thanlk very much nwp.

Comment: Don't include the answer in the question. Instead, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Right you are, I'll post it when I get home.

Comment: ClangCodeModel still has a lot of errors parsing C++17 headers. Hopefully they get clang 5.0 included in the build soon.

Comment: Another paranoic way is to delete all *.o *.exe Makefile* etc, check compiler (left bottom corner) and run `qmake`, rebuild project. It is better to clean do delete make-files IMHO ...

Answer (score 43):

`CONFIG += c++17` can be used with Qt 5.12 and later.

For Qt 5.11 and earlier, [it is not a recognized QMake flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) and you have to get your hands a bit dirty.

Adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` does the job for GCC & Clang; for MSVC you will [probably need to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759740) `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: This is true, but it was the clean and build again that actually fixed my issue, so anyone reading this, remember to do that too

Comment: QtCreator 4.6 and Qt 5.10 with both `CONFIG += c++17` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17`, works here.

Comment: @Alexander I can't use `<filesystem>` when I add those. Are you sure it works for things that only exist in C++17?

Comment: @Alexander maybe it's build-tools specific. For MSVC, I had to change the second one to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++17` -- I got the correctly formatted MSVC C++17 flag by inspecting the build output of a VS2017 C++ project that was explicitly set to c++17.

Comment: Needed to use `<optional>` with msvc and adding `CONFIG += c++17` worked for me on Qt 5.12.1 and QtCreator 4.8.1

Comment: `CONFIG += c++17` doesn't get the job done for me with Qt 5.12.1 on Windows 10 with MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit. However, `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` still gets the job done.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit 3/2019:** You can use `CONFIG += c++17` since Qt 5.12.

---

The actual flag is `c++1z`, not `c++17`. In short, to get C++17 support, you don't need to modify `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` and can instead simply use `CONFIG += c++1z`.

Discussion on the reason why can be [found in this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67527), but it pretty much amounts to "we implemented it as `c++1z` before C++17 was standardized, and now we won't bother aliasing it."

Note: I realize you just needed a clean and rebuild. I'm answering the underlying question of "what flags do I need to use to enable C++17 support?"

Comment: Neither work with Qt 5.12.4 and LLVM 8.0.0 using clang-cl. I don't know how to use the normal clang cli instead.

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html, c++1z is deprecated. c++17 is prefered

Comment: @jjcf89 That's for gcc. These are flags fed to QtCreator that determine what flags get sent to the compiler, be it gcc, MSVC, et cetera.

Comment: `<thumbs_up>`I have Qt 5.11.3 and the "CONFIG += c++1z" worked. Creator version 4.8.2 `</thumbs_up>`

Answer (score 3):

#### By Example C++17 C++20 Builds with Qt5 version 5.15.3 (and above) on Linux (or similar on Windows)

**Summary:**
Inside CMakeLists.txt file for an application written in C++17 and using Qt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
project(helloworld VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

A qt project configuration  eg mygame.pro may have **c++1z** for C++17 or **c++2a** for C++20 or **c++11** for older projects:

```
CONFIG += c++1z
```

On the command line of *configure* eg a C++20 project config, always use a shadow build:

```
../configure -c++std c++2a
cmake --build .. --parallel
```

Windows or Linux compiler command arguments examples with or without qt; at time of writing C++20 is c++2a  and C++17 is c++1z others to follow.

```
$ g++ -std=c++2a hello_linux_is_the_worlds_device_future.cpp  
c:\hello> cl /std=c++1z /EHsc hello_windows_is_in_decline.cpp
```

On windows notice the forward /slash.

**More Detail:**
I have found that building a new C++ project or even building **ALL** of qt5 open source thus creating my own qt release (which is tough) is possible by C++17 or C++20 (Qt6 requires at least C++17).  I cloned and then checked out version qt5 5.15 i.e. ALL of qt5 open source and built it using C++20 - the build takes 23GB ... **you don't need to do all that.**

**Note the config examples below,** ... 4 hours of build on a fast PC are super fussy and I managed eventually. Anyway the point is that Qt5.15 was happy to *build itself* with the C++17 or C++20 settings (in my case using gcc g++-8 or g++-9) by example:

1. Just take a look at this [cmake Get Started (qt6 C++17 example)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html) but 20 works just as well)
2. Qt5 open source code total build of qt5.15.3 with C++20 configure example:-

   mkdir qt5-build

   cd qt5-build

   ../configure  -release  -opensource  -nomake examples  -nomake tests 
   -skip qtdocgallery **-c++std c++2a** -confirm-license -opengl desktop 
   -platform linux-g++-64   # put this all on one-line please.

   cmake --build .. --parallel

OR use **make -j4**  as I did.

Considerable care was taken to write this for my own notes which I share, **I am happy to make corrections myself and suggestions are welcome; never ever hack into an authors work and change it! Just as I do not go into a public library and remove pages from books.** Examples count more than non-solutions, however examples age faster!

Answer (score 2):

For Windows: 
I'm download **qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.1**, icncluded MinGW32.
For MinGW64 I'm download **qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0** and install only compiler.
Configure QtCreator, as says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335424/how-to-use-mingw-64-with-qt-creator).
Create new project and add **QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++1z** to .pro file ([gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html#cxx)).
For test, try compile this simple code:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> foo() 
{
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();
}
```