# Tell QMake -std=C++17. QMAKE_CXXFLAGS overridden

Tags: c++, gcc, qt5, c++17, qmake

I use Qt 5.9.1 and all works fine.  Except of one little nuisance: it overrides my `-std=C++17`.

#### The project:

```
#CONFIG += c++14 #makes -std=gnu++1y 
#CONFIG += c++17  # is not supported by Qt591
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
TARGET = equipment
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += ....
....
```

#### Compile instructions:

```
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++17 -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC
-DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB  
-I../app -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64
/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ 
-o test0.o ../test0.cc
```

We can see two `-std=` and the second `-std=gnu++11` by QMake overrides mine first `-std=c++17`.

#### How can I tell QMake to use `-std=C++17`?

Comment: I just read https://forum.qt.io/topic/11565/qmake_cxxflags-overriden/2 : maybe using `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` instead of `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` whould make your flag override the other...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use c++17 features using g++ 7.2 in QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610996/cant-use-c17-features-using-g-7-2-in-qtcreator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `CONFIG += c++1z` and if it doesn't work pass it to compiler with `QMAKE_CXXFLAG`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. But the reason was that `pkg-config` included the dependency flag of the target library (`-std=с++11`).  For the `g++` compiler, the last flag has the highest priority. And `qmake` adds library flags and their dependencies after yours.