# 'Filesystem' member not in 'std' namespace

Tags: c++, macos, runtime-error, qt-creator

I have some code intending to get the file size of a PNG image (from a different stack overflow post).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstddef>
#include <filesystem>

const char* INPUT_FILENAME = "test.png";

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    size_t size = 0;

    std::cout << "Attempting to open " << INPUT_FILENAME << std::endl;

    file.open( INPUT_FILENAME, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate );
    char* data = 0;

    file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
//    size = file.tellg();
    size = std::filesystem::file_size(INPUT_FILENAME);
    std::cout << "File size: " << size << std::endl;
    file.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

    data = new char[ size - 8 + 1 ];
    file.seekg( 8 ); // skip the header
    file.read( data, size );
    data[ size ] = '\0';
    std::cout << "Data size: " << std::strlen( data ) << std::endl;
}
```

Upon running I get the error `no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'std::__fs::filesystem'. Even attempting to use the latter function results in errors of its own. I need help figuring if this is an issue with not having all the correct packages installed, or possibly my IDE settings? I should note I am running on a MacBook OS 11.2.3 and QtCreator 5.14.2.

Comment: What compiler are you using (clang?), and what version? [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) was only introduced in C++17. If your compiler doesn't have full C++17 support, it may not implement `std::filesystem`, or it may only offer a provisional implementation as [`std::experimental::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that your compiler doesn't support std::filesystem.

There *IS* such a thing as "[std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)" ... depending on your compiler.

This link might help:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192230/421195
>
> `CONFIG += c++17` can be used with Qt 5.12 and later.
>
> For Qt 5.11 and earlier, it is not a recognized QMake flag and you
> have to get your hands a bit dirty.
>
> Adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` does the job for GCC & Clang;
> for MSVC you will probably need to specify `/std:c++17` or
> `/std:c++latest`

See also [Compile With C++17 Mac](https://izziswift.com/compile-with-c17-mac/)

If neither option works, please post back with your specific compiler version.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me! I have run into the next (possibly related) issue in the suspect line of code `size = std::filesystem::file_size(INPUT_FILENAME);`. I know longer get the filesystem member error, but I receive `file_size' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15`. I am a bit confused as I am running 11.2.3. But if this is too unrelated I will consider submitting under a different thread.

Comment: You can always go Old School and simply call  [stat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), [fstat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) or friends ;)