# How to debug in VS Code: Windows 10 and MinGW

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to approaching to VS Code, I've Windows and Ubuntu on VM but i'd prefere a lot to debug on windows.

My teacher told us to use MinGW, and i'm using it for coding/compiling with no problem, i've already setted Win environment variables.
I'm new to debugging world and maybe it's hard to start with VS Code, I don't know.
I'm trying to follow lot of tutorial and i don't know if I'm doing it right. 
I must say that i'm using a Makefile instead of compiling in VS Code, i don't know if there is any difference.
Here is my standard Makefile:

```
all: Prog.exe

Prog.exe: main.o
    g++ main.o -o Prog.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c -g -Iinclude main.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.exe
```

1) I only know that the parameter "-g" includes debug information, is that enough for the compiling process in order to debug?

2) I'm following VS Code tutorials to set launch.json file, and i think I'm doing it right:

**launch.json:**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "I:/Documenti/.../Prove debug/Prog.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Abilita la riformattazione per gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I found that on VS Code site:

> - tasks.json (build instructions)
> - launch.json (debugger settings)
> - c_cpp_properties.json (compiler path and IntelliSense settings)

3) So i only need launch.json?
If i don't have any .json file it asks me to choose between different Configs:

Environment Config

[image: Environment Config]

4) it only seems to work the second one, but it skips breakpoints and it's useless...
Can i usee "GDB" on windows? If i try to use GDB, after set all launch.json i get this error:

GDB error

[image: GDB error]

5) I'd prefere to debug on windows with MinGW, is it possible?

**EDIT:** I solved, the problems were 2 big (a, b) and 1 small (c);
a. the `"program"` directory;
b. the gdb/compiler directory;
c. the task.json file which is not needed if you compile with makefile (or manually with terminal).

a: i replaced `"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` with the full directory of my program;

b: I have 2 different directory of MinGW (so 2 directory of gdb):
    - One which i manually installed (in C:);
    - The other I installed inside Qt (inside F:);
when VS Code automatically generate "launch.json" it sets me `"miDebuggerPath"` (gdb path) to the gdb installed with Qt (maybe for the order in Win10 environment paths) and I've always changed it to the other directory... Probably if I want to change directory I should set it in more files, and there was an error of 2 different gdb directory. I leaved the automatic directory (inside Qt, in F:);

c: I had an error of the task over the debug that was already working, so I realized that there were two different activities. I solved deleting the entire line `"preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"` and deleting `"task.json"` file.

Comment: I can't answer for VSCode, but you can debug [using QtCreator/mingw-w64/msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335424/how-to-use-mingw-64-with-qt-creator)

Comment: Thanks @M.M, i've already setted Qt for MinGW and I'll try, but i would like to solve this, I think I need it to understand a lot of little things :)
Can't you answer to no one of my points? like how should i compile for debugging? is the parameter "-g" enough?

Comment: I would use `-g` and `-O0`, also check that there aren't any strip flags being passed to the linker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes. the `-g` switch is all you need. Just to be clear I'm compiling my program as

```
gcc -g prog.c
```

2) Set the `"externalConsole"` options as "true". For some reason, this does not work when it is false. The rest seems okay.

3) I can debug just fine with only the `launch.json` file and nothing else

4) The second one `C++ (Windows)` option is for the Windows C/C++ compiler which you can install using MSBuild tools alongside Visual Studio and use the `cl.exe` compiler instead of gcc/g++. In case you want to try the Windows compiler, you need to compile using the -Zi switch (just like -g switch in gcc/g++) and your compilation command will be

```
cl -Zi path\to\prog.cpp -o a.exe
```

But of course, if you are using MinGW/gcc/g++ you don't need this.

I can't say for sure, but your error looks like your path to the program is not correct. Make appropriate changes in the `"program"` in your launch.json file just for reference my `program` path value is

```
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
```

Here, this `a.exe` is located at the root of the repository/workspace of VS Code

5) Well, I'm able to debug in windows with MinGW just fine, so it should be possible.